# Forcefield as collider with dynamic hair

Tags: particles, hair

Having a separate collision object works, but with fast movement I still get a lot penetration through the mesh.

Apparently it can be done better with a forcefield but I cannot get it to work like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeFZbp_UC0o

or this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASFD9s0j6Ng

I have my emitter mesh with the hair particles and a second mesh that I set as force field with the same settings as in Video 1, but the force field has no effect on the dynamic hair. What am I missing? Maybe a setting in the particles system itself?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it does work afterall when I increase the strength to a much higher value like 500 or more.

As you can see I got another issue then though with the distance, which I will ask in a new post.

[image]